# webclient response is different to the IE response

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webclient

When i call download data on my webclient, the response is different to when i open it in IE. I am trying to call www.yell.com searching for a type of company in a certain location. When i get my response it finds 2 companies but doesnt actually display them, it just says 2 results found. In IE it actually displays the results. The URLs are exactly the same so i dont know what could be causing this?

Comment: Could it be that yell.com is checking the browser identity and only returning responses for "real" browsers?  Some sites do this to prevent scripts from extracting the content of their databases.

Comment: i put a user agent on the headers though posing as IE?

Comment: @xoxo: I don't know, you tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Maybe the website uses JavaScript to load additional data after the main page has loaded? Get [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and check what passes through the pipes.
- Is there some sort of CSS/Javascript hide/unhide work done on page load? Check with IE8's built-in script debugger.
- Maybe there's a CSS stylesheet loaded which hides those results, or are they physically missing from the response?
- How do the webclient/IE headers differ? Some sites send different content depending e.g. on User-Agent header ("If this is not IE/FF/Opera/Webkit, it's probably a bot, send different content"). Pay attention to other header fields as well. Again, check using Fiddler.
- Are the results in IE displayed as HTML? Is it not some Flash/Java/Silverlight/whatever object? (strange but possible)
- Is there some cookie action going on? Some sites set a cookie on access, and use it to keep state - e.g. "you haven't gone through the search page, no results for you". Again, Fiddler to the rescue.
- Does the site work OK in other browsers? If not, what's broken? (not a problem per se, but can give you a hint where a problem could be)

Comment: i checked fiddler, its not calling any javascript to load!

Comment: ok i had a proper look, it sets a load of properties inside the html i think with javasctipt. Number of results = 2, number to display= 0. but in IE the number to display is 2 also. how do i change these properties or is it not possible??